# Mercadopago Checkout Basico - El soporte de Mercadopago no ayuda

Tags: mercadopago

Estoy tratandod e crear un boton con mercadopago, y es imposible, esta gente no responde consultas y la documentacion no es pobre es miserable, mi codigo es este

```
    <html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Pago Mercadopago</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h2>Mercadopago pago:</h2>

    <?php

    require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';  //Aqui coloca la ruta en donde descargaste el sdk de mercadopago

    MercadoPago\SDK::setAccessToken('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'); // Ya que vas a hacer pruebas de pago, aqui tu access token de prueba, luego puedes agregar el token de produccion

    // Crea un objeto de preferencia
    $preference = new MercadoPago\Preference();

    // Crea un ítem en la preferencia
    $item = new MercadoPago\Item();
    $item->title = 'Producto 1';
    $item->quantity = 1;
    $item->unit_price = 300.00; //Detalle aca, si tu previamente tienes configurado en tu cuenta que eres de algun pais que no maneje decimales en el valor, el valor debe ser entero, sino mercadopago arrojara error
    $preference->items = array($item);
    $preference->save();

    
    
    ?>

    <form action="/procesar-pago" method="POST">
        <script src="https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/integrations/v1/web-payment-checkout.js" data-preference-id="<?php echo $preference->id; ?>">
        </script>
    </form>
    
    

</body>
</html>
```

el error es este

Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'easy handle already used in multi handle' in /home/elbazarcom/public_html/vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/src/MercadoPago/RestClient.php:190
Stack trace:
#0 /home/elbazarcom/public_html/vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/src/MercadoPago/RestClient.php(228): MercadoPago\RestClient->exec(Array)
#1 /home/elbazarcom/public_html/vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/src/MercadoPago/Manager.php(90): MercadoPago\RestClient->post('/checkout/prefe...', Array)
#2 /home/elbazarcom/public_html/vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/src/MercadoPago/Entity.php(256): MercadoPago\Manager->execute(Object(MercadoPago\Preference), 'post', Array)
#3 /home/elbazarcom/public_html/mp-test.php(27): MercadoPago\Entity->save()
#4 {main}
thrown in /home/elbazarcom/public_html/vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/src/MercadoPago/RestClient.php on line 190

me podran indicar cual es el problema?

Gracias

Comment: La documentación de mercado pago es miserable. Completamente de acuerdo. Pocos ejemplos, pocos escenarios. En Github los ejemplos incompletos, un desastre y hacen millones y millones de dolares. Vergonzoso..

Answer (score 0):

Esta bien...debe ser tu servidor... tengo la misma integración corriendo en php 7.
Aunque la cambie por:

```
$url = $preference->init_point;            
header("Location: $url");
```

Answer (score 0):

Puede ser que sea el servidor, ahora esta solucion que me da

```
$url = $preference->init_point;            
header("Location: $url");
```

que reemplaza o donde lo implementa

Gracias